# Unable to generate rspec in rails project, "uninitialized constant RSpec (NameError) is thrown"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

```
>: rails generate rspec:install
/Users/prashanth_sams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_formatter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant RSpec (NameError)
from /Users/prashanth_sams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/allure-rspec-0.6.7/lib/allure-rspec/formatter.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/prashanth_sams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/allure-rspec-0.6.7/lib/allure-rspec/formatter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/prashanth_sams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/allure-rspec-0.6.7/lib/allure-rspec.rb:3:in `require'
from /Users/prashanth_sams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/allure-rspec-0.6.7/lib/allure-rspec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/prashanth_sams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
from /Users/prashanth_sams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/prashanth_sams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
from /Users/prashanth_sams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
from /Users/prashanth_sams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
from /Users/prashanth_sams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
from /Users/prashanth_sams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /Users/prashanth_sams/Desktop/MAC/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/prashanth_sams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
from /Users/prashanth_sams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I tried the below cmd in Terminal

> bundle exec rails generate rspec:install

but no luck :(

Placed the below in my Gemfile

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
end
```

Comment: constant is  `Rspec` I believe

Comment: Hi! @Малъ Скрылевъ Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: which rails do you use?

Answer (score 0):

May be the version of Rspec is incompatible: downgrade the version of rspec or just write:

```
gem 'rspec-rails'
```

then you can update it:

```
bundle update rspec-rails
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create the spec folder and spec_helper.rb using

**`rspec --init`**

[image]